# Count the bits set in 1 for binary number in C++

Tags: c++, bit

How many bits are set in the number 1 in one binary number of 15 digits.

I have no idea how to start this one. Any help/hints?

Comment: Here are some codes for very efficient solutions: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive

Comment: `__builtin_popcount` or `__popcnt` may be useful

Comment: The number 1 has a single bit set, no matter how many binary digits you write it with. If you write 1 in binary with 15 digits (e.g. `0000000000000001`) one bit is set; If you write it with 2 digits (`01`) only one bit is set, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like homework, so I'll be all vague and cryptic. But helpful, since that's what we do here at SO.

First, let's figure out how to check the first bit. Hint: you want to set all other bits of the variable to zero, and check the value of the result. Since all other bits are zero, the value of the variable will be the value of the first bit (zero or one). More hint: to set bits to zero, use the AND operation.

Second, let's move the second bit to the first position. There's an operation in C++ just for that.

Third, rinse and repeat until done. Count them ones as you do so.

EDIT: so in pseudocode, assuming `x` is the source variable

```
CountOfOnes=0
while X != 0
    Y = the first bit of X          (Y becomes either 0 or 1)
    CountOfOnes = CountOfOnes + Y
    X = X right shift 1
```

Specifically for C++ implementation, you need to make X an unsigned variable; otherwise, the shift right operation will act up on you.

Oh, and << and >> operators are exactly bitwise shift. In C++, they're sometimes overridden in classes to mean something else (like I/O), but when acting on integers, they perform bit shifting.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, it's homework and I can't tag. However, I'm not looking to be spoofed at all, I want to learn more (it's optional exercise). So, we never spoke before about bits and how to count them, I got interested. Can you maybe add a sample code or psuedo code to start from?

Comment: Well, for a straightforward, built-for-understanding version of the code, try to understand what the shift operators do (either left shift or right shift, aka `<<` and `>>`) and what the bitwise-AND operator `&` does.  You want to visit all the bits and count up the bits that aren't zero.  What would that look like as a loop?

Comment: As far as I know, the << and >> operators execute what's right/left of them. In case <<, it executed what's on the left side, so if we started with `cout << endl;`, it will execute cout which is a member of the ostream. And the bitwise AND operator `&` checks each bit of the first number to the second one. And yes, I thought of using & in this exercise, but we only have one number.

Comment: The other number for & is the number where the first bit is 1 and the rest are zero. Can you think of such a number? :)))